# Cannot create Java Web project in NetBeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

I cannot create Java Web project in NetBeans. When the wizard asks me to select the "Java EE Version" on "Server and Settings" page, there are not options to select for java version. Do I have to install Java EE separately somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible to install Java EE separately, and configure Netbeans to use it.

IDE makers typically don't include the Java EE by default, since it is a huge extra download.  Looking at the [Netbeans download](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) page though, I see "Java EE" listed.

Comment: I have uninstalled current version and downloaded the Netbeans Java EE bundle and it works. Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

It depends which bundle you downloaded (see [available bundles](http://netbeans.org/downloads/)).  Maybe you need to download the Java EE SDK separately ([download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html)).

Comment: I think I have to download it separately. After I download the file, where should I put it so Netbeans can detect it?

Comment: Look into the config file at _nb-install-dir/etc/netbeanc.conf_. There is an entry `jdkhome`

Answer (score 3):

You need a servlet container to test your app and you need some libraries from Java EE to compile your app.

You can download glassfish, Oracle's reference EE implementation directly from netbeans and it will integrate it into your IDE for you.

Open the services panel (if it is not visible select it under the window menu), right-click Servers and choose add server. Select Glassfish 3 and the you can download it. If you already downloaded another Sevlet container, you can use this dialog to integrate it into the IDE here as well.

The services tab can then be used to restart the container (glassfish or Tomcat) if needed.

Comment: You can also download and install GlassFish directly from the wizard for creating a web app.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to end up in this state and the easiest way to move forward is to do the following:

Press the Add... button that appears to the right of the combo box labelled 'Server'.  It is labelled with a red 1 in the image below.

This brings up the wizard to register a server in the IDE.

Pick 'GlassFish Server 3+' on the first page of the wizard and press the Next button.

On the second page of the wizard (which is the one that appears in the image below), you can enter the name of a directory that will hold the installed bits.  Click on the checkbox labelled 'I have read and accept the license' (labeled with a red 2). This will enable the Download Now... button. This will bring up a dialog that allows you to decide which version of GlassFish you want to install.

[image]

After the server is registered you will be able to select the Java EE version that you want to use for your Java Web App project.